# Chrome downloading file after 100%

Tags: google-chrome, file-download

I was downloading something today and I know it is only 1.8 GB, but after downloading 1.8/1.8 GB, the weirdest thing happened. Chrome kept downloading the file and the progress bar started showing the loading animation and the file size kept increasing until it finally stopped after 2.5 GB. It was a video file and it says it's 2.5 GB on my disk and it doesn't even play. How does this stuff happen?

Answer (score 0):

One of the numerous response headers that's part of the HTTP protocol is the `Content-Length` header.  This essentially lets the server tell the client how big the data being sent in the response is.  Chrome, like most sensible browsers, uses this header to determine what to show for the total file size when downloading a file, as well as computing the displayed download progress.

There are two issues with this though:

- Servers aren't strictly required to send this header (it's only needed in some circumstances, not all).  It's rare to see servers not send it for stuff that's actual files on their local disk, but it's not unusual when it's content that's being generated dynamically and sent as it's generated (for example, ZIP archives generated on-the-fly by some cloud storage services to allow customers to download groups of files all at once) fall into this category).  When this happens, Chrome will display download progress without an actual completion percentage, but the usual loading bar to indicate the download is continuing.
- For compatibility reasons, in cases where the header isn't required, but is sent anyway, it has to be treated as advisory information instead of being a strict indication of the size of the response.  There are too many reasons to list here for this, but the upshot is that when fetching (or downloading) a resource, Chrome (and most browsers) keep fetching data until the server stops sending it in these cases because they can't trust that what the header said is accurate (in fact, Chrome will hide minor discrepancies between the reported file size and actual file size when downloading

What happened in your case was a result of that second issue.  When it hit the 'full' file size and kept getting data, Chrome eventually switched to displaying things like it does when it doesn't know the size of the file it's downloading.  The two possible causes that come to mind for this are either a bug (either in the server, or in some intermediary system), or malicious activity (probably a man-in-the-middle attack or compromised server if it's this case).

Either way, this should probably be reported to whoever owns the site you downloaded the video from, as either case is likely to be bad news for them.

---

On a side note, you can also see behavior similar to this, but without the increasing file size, if Chrome was able to fetch the entire file from the network faster than it could write it to the local disk.